# Import error:dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

I am trying to create an IOS app with Kivy and OpenCV, but following kivy build, xcode outputs the following error:

> Import error: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)

```
./toolchain.py pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

installs the packages in the python 2.7 folder even though python 3.7 is the host python.

OpenCV and Kivy work fine in pycharm.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have also tried building Kivy with python2 and a similar error comes up
https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios

Comment: Try using `py -2 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python` for Python2 and `py -3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python` for Python3

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the ./toolchain.py file --> replace `pip_path = sh.which("pip")` with `pip_path = sh.which("pip3")`
Then try running `./toolchain.py pip install opencv-contrib-python`